# How to fix camping tent properly on LowePro Photosport BP 300 AW II

Tags: camping, tents, backpacks

I have  [LowePro Photosport BP 300  AW II](https://www.lowepro.com/uk-en/photo-sport-bp-300-aw-ii-black-lp36890-pww/) backpack for hiking and a camera. The old model of this bag had the proper straps to fix the tent but in the new model (which I have), I don't know how do I fix a tent the bottom of the bag (or anywhere else).

**Old model of the bag:**
[image]

**My bag:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A good carrying spot for long, bulky items is to put it under the backpack lid (the flap over the top of the pack) placed sideways, parallel to the shoulders. This actually has some advantages over carrying on the bottom of the pack, because the weight is over your center of gravity, rather than behind and beneath it, which would have a tendency to lean you backwards. The main disadvantage is that you have to remove the top-mounted item anytime you go into the pack's main pocket.

I can't find any good non-copyrighted images, so here's a link to a page with some examples (scroll down to the 'Floating Lids' section):
[sectionhiker.com](https://sectionhiker.com/backpacking-external-attachment-guide-how-to-carry-gear-on-the-outside-of-a-backpack/)

Comment: If you use someone else's picture, you need to credit them

Comment: Whoops, my bad- I'll remove and see if I can find a different one.

Comment: Hi Patrick N, if I'm not mistaken, downloading a picture from a website like the one you linked  is fine as long as you credit that website as the source. To me it's the same as quoting text as long as we list the source. At least I hope it's okay because I do it all the time and would never intentionally break that rule!!

Comment: Unfortunately copyright laws for pictures are different from texts there. Depending on the jurisdiction and license used for the photo, this could well be illegal.

Comment: Someone had posted a comment (since deleted) basically saying that there could be copyright issues, so I figured it was better safe than sorry to just link to the page